# Start and stop azure analysis service in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-management-api

I have MVC application I am able to connect Analysis Service.
I want to start Analysis Service programmatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You got an answer, and that is great! But, StackOverflow is not some kind of human google service. Just like [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50235758/how-to-start-and-pause-azure-analysis-service?noredirect=1) this is too broad and does not show much effort from your side. Please read [the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then you will better understand what question generally are allowed and do get answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Analysis Services Management nuget package. [You can find the package here.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Analysis/2.0.3)

Once installed you will need to create a new instance and leverage the [Resume and Suspend operations](https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Analysis.IServersOperations.BeginSuspendWithHttpMessagesAsync(String,String,Dictionary%3CString,List%3CString%3E%3E,CancellationToken)).

There is a fair bit of plumbing to do in order to get the Management API set up and authenticated, you can follow [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn722415.aspx#bk_createcreds) to give you a head start.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I have .net framework 4.5.1. Not able to install this package as it is compatible 4.5.2 framework and above.

Comment: Look for a previous version that is compatible.

Comment: I have gone through this IServersOperations interface.

I am using the following method:
BeginCreate(this IServersOperations operations, string resourceGroupName, string serverName,AnalysisServicesServer serverParameters);

So is this method correct for start analysis service?

how we can initialize these two parameters:
IServersOperations operations
AnalysisServicesServer serverParameters

Comment: Create will create a now instance, you want the BeginResume and BeginSuspend.

Comment: if I want to start analysis service which function should I use?

How can we initialize IServersOperations operations?